# Adding Facebook comment control dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, facebook

Is it possible to add the Facebook Comments control dynamically?  I have a list of items that I want users to be able to comment on, but I don't want a bunch of comment controls appearing on the page at one time. I want to be able to click an 'Add comment' button and it pops up the comment box pointing to the right item?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by adding Comments Social plugin code to the DOM and calling `FB.XFBML.parse()`